# How can set highlighting item in gallery onitemclick in android

Tags: android

I want to highlight the gallery selected item when itemonclick.

My gallery getview module

```
@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub



            if(convertView==null){


                holder=new ViewHolder();
                convertView=inflate.inflate(R.layout.customfiltergallery, null);
                holder.image=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.glview);
                holder.text=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gltext);

                //holder.image.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(100, 100));  
                holder.image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

                holder.image.setPadding(1,1,1,1);
                //holder.text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
                //holder.image.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);


                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }


            else
            {
                holder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }


            holder.image.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);





            return convertView;

        }
```

I want to highlight the selected gallery item.
 When i put the click listener for `imageview` inside the `Getview()` ,the application is slow down...

Comment: What have you tryed? What gallery? More details please

Comment: show your code please... getView() code

Comment: look in to this artical same way you have to make it for gallary : http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/android-changing-listview-background-colors or you can also try custom gallary.

Comment: put your code of customfiltergallery.xml

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [android.widget.Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) (wich is deprecated in api 16), you just need to setOnItemClickListener to your gallery object.

```
android.widget.Gallery gallery = (android.widget.Gallery) findViewById(R.id.your_gallery);

    gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Here you should hightlight v object as you want
        // And save item id to dehightlight previous selected item
        // Dehighlight previous selected item if it is not null
    }
});
```

I would make it like that

Comment: Amm, I do not how you hightlighting it, but easiest solution - set to view at previous position result from getView(previousHighlitedElement). But I would prefer to search item by itemId (not position, because may be you want to change their order in future) and do reverse actions as you do for hightlighting